# D3 treemap json implementation with d3.nest

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-visualization

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
 <title>My treemap</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.node {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre;
  background: #ddd;
}

.node-label,
.node-value {
  margin: 4px;
}

.node-value {
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.node-value {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<body>
<svg width="1000" height="1000">
    <g></g>
  </svg>
  <script>
const margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10};
   var   width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
   var   height = 960 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
   var   color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20b);
   var treemap = d3.treemap()
     .size([width, height])
     .padding(1)
     .round(true);
   var json_data=d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/data/cars.json", function(error, data) {
   if (error) throw error;
    var nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Origin; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.Cylinders; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.Miles_per_Gallon; })
    .rollup(function(leaves){return {"value" : leaves.length}
    })
    .entries(data);
    console.log(nested_data);
    var root = d3.hierarchy(nested_data);
    root.sum(function(d) {
     return d.value;})

        treemap(root);
        var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
          .selectAll('g')
          .data(root.descendants())
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'})

        nodes
          .append('rect')
          .attr('width', function(d) { return (d.x1 - d.x0)*10; })
          .attr('height', function(d) { return (d.y1 - d.y0)*10; })
          .attr('fill', function(d){ return color(d.data.key);
          })

        nodes
          .append('text')
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.key;})


  
   });
  
  </script>
</body>
```

I am trying to create a treemap out of non-hierarchical data structure (sample cars.json data structure). Now I am confused why my code does not show anything on the browser. 
I am specifically having trouble with appending nested key and values into the root and node of the tree. Can anybody please explain this to me? 
Also, can you show me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using? I can't get your code to run beyond the first couple of lines with any of the versions I've got on my machine.

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>

This is the version I am using and I have put this on head tag

Comment: I added code snippet for my case for easy editing. You can check it through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was almost complete; the only things missing were that you needed to add a fake root node to your hierarchy, to specify the accessor for the children, and to fix the value for the leaf nodes, which had an extra layer of nesting that needed to be removed.

#### Leaf node value:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
[...]
.rollup(function(leaves) {
  return {
    value: leaves.length
  }
})
.entries(data);
```

results in leaf nodes like so:

```
{ value: { value: 5 } }
```

remove the extra `value:` from the `rollup` call:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
[...]
.rollup(function(leaves) {
  return leaves.length
})
.entries(data);
```

and now your leaf nodes look like so:

```
{ value: 5 }
```

#### Fake root node

Ensure all your nested data is collected in the same hierarchy by adding a fake root:

```
d3.hierarchy({ values: nested_data })
```

#### Child node accessor

Specify the accessor for the children as otherwise d3 will look for `x.children`, and if it isn't there, will assume the node is a leaf:

```
d3.hierarchy({ value: nested_data }, function(d) { return d.values })
```

Result:

```js
const margin = {
  top: 40,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 10,
  left: 10
};
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 960 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20b);
var treemap = d3.treemap()
  .size([width, height])
  .padding(1)
  .round(true);
var json_data = d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/data/cars.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.Origin;
    })
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.Cylinders;
    })
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.Miles_per_Gallon;
    })
    .rollup(function(leaves) {
      return leaves.length
    })
    .entries(data);

  var root = d3.hierarchy({
      values: nested_data
    }, d => d.values)
    .sum(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    })

  treemap(root);
  var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
    })

  nodes
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return (d.x1 - d.x0) * 10;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return (d.y1 - d.y0) * 10;
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
      return color(d.data.key);
    })

  nodes
    .append('text')
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.key;
    })
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.node {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre;
  background: #ddd;
}

.node-label,
.node-value {
  margin: 4px;
}

.node-value {
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.node-value {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<title>My treemap</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="1000" height="1000">
    <g></g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have trouble understanding these relations in nests in D3.